# Disable integrated GPU (Intel HD Graphics 3000) on Sony VAIO VPCSE

Tags: ati, intel-graphics, sony, hybrid-graphics, gpu

I have a Sony VAIO VPCSE2L9E and want do disable the integrated GPU. I want to install the fglrx packages to use the full GPU power of my AMD Radeon HD 6630M. Here is the link for the technical data of the notebook: [Sony homepage for VPCSE](http://www.sony.at/product/vn-s-series/vpcse2l9e)

How can I do this? Is there a way to blacklist the integrated GPU on startup or is there an other solution for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution on: 
[Follow the Instructions from post #1 (Step1 -3)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450/)
I downloaded and installed the latest Catalyst package (12.6).

After that, I am able to change the integrated and discrete GPU via ATI Control Center or a single command on terminal!

Additional information can be found on:
[the corresponding Launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/813809)